# Upper-Case Method on Database or in Java Code?

Tags: java, database

Hy,

Lets say you have Varchar-Database values in a column that are cAmeLCaSe and you always want to display them UPPERCASE in a view.

Is it now better to select those entrys using the (for example) UPPER-Function of Oracle 
or to loop the results and call the .toUpperCase() Method from within the Java Code after the selection has been made?

I know its a bit of a general question and i will of corse comment after having made performance messurments of the above two possibilitys. But i am more after a good source of information that addresses such questions in general (like for example "is it better do run sorting db- side or in programm-code?" and questions like this for common Solutions like .Net/Java and Oracle/ MSSQL Server.

Many thanks you took the time to read this questions, i appreciate any input and wish you a great day.

Regards
Jan

Comment: If it's only place where is used (in view), you could also store value in table in uppercase...

Comment: Youre absolutly right, in generall if you need those values to be uppercase one should already store them as uppercase. In our case the values unfortunately need to be sotred cammelcase for other systems.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on where and how the uppercased value is used.

If this is *only* used in the frontend (I assume with "*view*" you did **not** mean a database view) then I'd go for a `toUpperCase()` ideally using the user's locale.

If you are using the uppercase value for comparison I'd use the Oracle function to ensure that the you have a consistent behaviour. I'm think of e.g. a condition where you compare the column value to a string constant: `WHERE upper(foobar) = upper('SomeValue')` If you used Java's `toUpperCase()` that might apply different (locale dependent) rules than Oracle would use.

Comment: Very many thanks for your input, indeed i have never thought about locale specific rules that might apply on the java side.

Answer (score 1):

I believe always my code should be database independent.

```
 String upper = string.toUpperCase();
```

Because,it's database independent.If I shift my database to some other,I need not to change my code.

In a nutshell your **specific** requirements should  take in to consideration.

Comment: Very many thanks for your input, considered the above locale- specific point that will not be a problem for us i now go for your solution considering simpler DB migration.